# errors on imports

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I am just starting out with android.
I downloaded a sample project.  And getting some errors.

I have errors on all these imports.
Is this something wrong with my path?

The quick fix just gives fix project setup.

Any help?
thanks

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.gesture.Gesture;
import android.gesture.GestureLibraries;
import android.gesture.GestureLibrary;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView;
import android.gesture.Prediction;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very Common Problem, Try following thing,

- Right Click on Project --> Select Properties
- From the Left List Select Android
- Now from the Right List Select Proper "Project Build Target"

Sometimes this might not work because in your Project's Folder the .classpath will be in read only mode, so Just right Click on that file and remove read only mode.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I cannot right click on the Project Build Target.  There is only a checkbox.


<img src="http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/546/screenshotat20120217233.png" >
 

My eclipse is 
Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Should something be added to the path?

<img src="http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/69/screenshotat20120217234.png  >

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the steps to set up SDK, ADT Pluggin?

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I believe everything is installed correct.
Take a look at these screenshots:

![ADT](http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/3081/screenshotat20120218232.png)

![ADT](http://img859.imageshack.us/img859/8762/screenshotat20120216201.png)

![ADT](http://img521.imageshack.us/img521/665/screenshotat20120219190.png)

![ADT](http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/665/screenshotat20120219190.png)

any ideas?
thanks